# Aligning sums in math mode

Tags: formatting, align

What is the best way to typeset this? I found a way to do it, but it seems like an ugly workaround, and the + signs aren't aligned right.

[image: Sums]

The code I used:

```
    Let's evaluate the value of:
    $$(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1{2n})-(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n)$$
    in two ways. First way:
    \begin{align*}
    1+\frac12&+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\dotsb+\frac1{2n}\\
    -\phantom{{}+{}}(1&\phantom{{}+{}}+\phantom{\frac13}\frac12\phantom{{}+{}}
        +\phantom{\frac15}\frac13\phantom{{}+{}}+\phantom{\frac17}\dotsb+\frac1n)\\
    \cline{1-2}
    1-\frac12&+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\dotsb-\frac1{2n}
    \end{align*}
    Second way:
    \begin{align*}
    &1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\dotsb+\frac1{2n}\\
    -(&1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n)\\
    \cline{1-2}
    &\phantom{1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n+{}}\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\dotsb+\frac1{2n}
    \end{align*}
    Thus, they must be equal.
```

(Also: First post here, so I have no idea how to tag this.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to do this using `\halign` primitive:

```
\def\oo#1{{\displaystyle{1\over#1}}} % \oo = One Over #1

\vbox{\halign{&$#{}$\cr
   1 + &\oo2 + \oo3 + &\oo4 + \oo5 + &\oo6 + \oo7 + \cdots + \oo{2n}\cr
   \noalign{\smallskip}
   -   &(1 +          &\oo2 +        &\oo3 + \cdots {{}+ \oo{n}})\cr
   \noalign{\smallskip\hrule\smallskip}
   1 - &\oo2 + \oo3 - &\oo4 + \oo5 - &\oo6 + \oo7 + \cdots - \oo{2n}\cr
}}
\bye
```

[image: oo]

Comment: I think that this is the only one that managed to center the $+$ signs correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `alignat` environment has a somewhat simpler code. By the way, don't use `$$ … $$` for displayed equations, which is plain TeX code, as this can result in bad vertical spacing, but `\[ … \]`. I managed to have longdots in equation (they're perfectible!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Let's evaluate the value of:
\[ \Bigl(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1{2n}\Bigr)-\Bigl(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n\Bigr) \]
in two ways. First way:
\begin{alignat*}{6}
1 & +\frac12 &{} +\frac13 & +\frac14 & {}+\frac15 & + \frac16 {}+\frac17+\dotsb &{} +\frac1{2n}\\
 & -1 & & -\frac12 & & -\frac13 - \mathrlap{\dotsb\dotsb\mkern-8mu\dotsb} &{} -\frac1n\\
\cline{1-7}
1&-\frac12 &{}+\frac13 & -\frac14 &{}+\frac15 & -\frac16+\frac17-\dotsb &{} -\frac1{2n}
\end{alignat*}
Second way:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
1+\frac12+\frac13+\dotsb+\frac1n &{} +{}&\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\dotsb+\frac1{2n}\\
-1-\frac12-\frac13-\dotsb-\frac1n & \\
\cline{1-3}
& & \frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\dotsb+\frac1{2n}
\end{alignat*}
Thus, they must be equal.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to get started with a TABstack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\let\svbs\\

\begin{document}
\noindent in two ways.  First way:\par\medskip
{\centering
{\let\\\svbs
\tabbedShortstack[r]{%
&&1 & +\dfrac{1}{2}& +\dfrac{1}{3}& +\dfrac{1}{4}& +\dfrac{1}{5}& +\dfrac{1}{6}& 
+\dfrac{1}{7}&+ \dots+ & \dfrac{1}{2n}\\
&-&&(1&+&\dfrac{1}{2}&+&\dfrac{1}{3}&+&\dots+&\dfrac{1}{n})\\
\rlap{\protect\rule{67mm}{.6pt}}\\
&&1 & -\dfrac{1}{2}& +\dfrac{1}{3}& -\dfrac{1}{4}& +\dfrac{1}{5}& -\dfrac{1}{6}& 
+\dfrac{1}{7}&+ \dots- & \dfrac{1}{2n}
}
}\par\medskip}
Second way:
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for an array: the alignments can be better controlled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}

\newcommand{\rec}[1]{\frac{1}{\mathstrut#1}}
\newcommand{\cfl}[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\cdotfill}}
\newcommand{\cdotfill}{\cleaders\hbox{$\cdotp{}$}\hfill\kern0pt }

\begin{document}

Let's evaluate the value of
\[
\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}\Bigr)-
\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)
\]
in two ways. First way:
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{array}{
  r
  *{8}{ >{{}}c<{{}} >{\displaystyle}c }
}
1 &+& \rec{2} &+& \rec{3} &+& \rec{4} &+& \rec{5} &+& \rec{6} &+& \rec{7} &+& \dotsb &+& \rec{2n}
\\
  &-& 1       & &         &-& \rec{2} & &         &-& \rec{3} &-& \cfl{3}            &-& \rec{n}
\\
\midrule
1 &-& \rec{2} &+& \rec{3} &-& \rec{4} &+& \rec{5} &-& \rec{6} &+& \rec{7} &-& \dotsb &-& \rec{2n}
\end{array}
\]
Second way:
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{array}{
  >{\displaystyle}r
  >{{}}c<{{}} >{\displaystyle}c
}
1  + \rec{2} + \rec{3} + \dotsb + \rec{n} &+& \rec{n+1} + \rec{n+2} + \dots + \rec{2n}
\\
-1 - \rec{2} - \rec{3} - \dotsb - \rec{n}
\\
\midrule
& & \rec{n+1}+\rec{n+2}+\dots+\rec{2n}
\end{array}
\]
Thus, they must be equal.
\end{document}
```

[image]